# Connect the oscilloscope to equipment with a common neutral and ground

Tags: safety, earth, neutral

I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hT8kNtfQV8). At 3 minutes, the situation is shown when neutral and ground are joining. Why can this be dangerous? If we are talking about an oscilloscope, the crocodile must already be connected to the earth and nothing threatens me. The way I understand the connection, I showed in the picture. Is it possible to get "tickled" with such a picture?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what happens in the video, so the question stands on its own and no one has to watch the video to understand what you are asking and why.

Comment: all he is saying `Always be aware what the equipment probes are connected to. Never touch a probe if the other probe is connected to lethal voltage levels, because the meter may be providing a hazardous path between the two probes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that you incorrectly clamp the GND of the probe in the T1 of your "DUT", if your oscilloscope is floating, then all its grounded metals and shielding become a direct contact to the live wire. And you can get "tickled", as you said yourself.

In the picture you drew the GND probe was disconnected from the GND/Neutral conductor, but the measuring probe is still connected to the live wire. In that case, your oscilloscope will be referenced to the live voltage (if you measure the voltage with a multimeter from ground (earth) to any point on the oscilloscope circuit it will be "about the same" as the live wire).

I think your confusion (at least looking at that ball with L G N) stems from you thinking the GND of the oscilloscope is connected to the GND of the house wiring, which in that video is not the case (the oscilloscope is floating, no connection to the power outlet ground pin).